# How many orthogonal $4 \times 4$ matrices $A$ are there with $0< |(a)_{ij}| \leq 1/2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> How many orthogonal $4 \times 4$ matrices $A$ are there with $0< |(A)_{ij}| \leq 1/2$.

This is a question from a practice examination in graduate linear algebra. After some more thought, I believe there are $1704$ possible matrices. Here is why:

All the entries of such matrices must have absolute value $|1/2|$, otherwise the vector length of any column would be less unit length so $A$ would not be orthogonal.

Any column of $A$ has 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 negative values. There are 1, 4, 6, 4, and 1 possible columns for each of these cases, respectively.

Notice that if any column has an even number of negative values, then all the columns of $A$ must have an even number of negative values, otherwise there would be at least one pair of columns that's not pairwise orthogonal. Same for if any column has an odd number of negative values.

A simple (but tedious) counting argument shows that the number of possible matrices is $1704$.

Do others find this solution agreeable and/or perhaps have a faster method to count the possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially asking about the number of unique $4\times4$ [Hadamard matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix).

You may pick the signs of the entries in the first row at will. There are $2^4=16$ choices.

Without loss of generality, suppose the first row is $\frac12(1,1,1,1)$. Then the second row must have exactly two negative entries. There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to pick their positions.

Without loss of generality, suppose the second row is $\frac12(1,1,-1,-1)$. Then exactly one entry in the first half of the third row is positive and similarly in the second half. There are $2^2=4$ ways to pick the positions of the two positive entries.

The last row is confined in the one-dimensional space orthogonal to the first three rows, but we may pick its direction. There are two choices.

Therefore the answer is $16\times6\times4\times2=768$. See also [OEIS sequence A206711](https://oeis.org/A206711).

Comment: Thank you. How do you know that there will always be 6 ways to pick the positions in the second row? I see this is correct by verifying the cases (e.g. if there are 3 negative entries in the first row, then the second row has 1 or 3 negative entries, of which there are 6 choices), but is there a more elegant/faster way to deduce this rather than through counting?

Comment: @mathjacks The second row *must* have exactly two negative entries because we have assumed that the first row is $\frac12(1,1,1,1)$. More specifically, regardless of what the first row is, the entrywise *ratio* of the second row to the first row must contain exactly two -1s and exactly two 1s.